# format spec. field from views_embed_view

Tags: views

My problem is that when using views_embed_view, i need to 
format spec. field for vacillation, i mean i don't know the 
syntax to access the spec field while rendering.

e.g use foreach , if field-name, then .....do some thing. 
search around the API doc. and google, no luck. OR should i use
other API ? i don't know

below are my code put in tpl file. work fine, just don't how to formatting the fields

```
  $arg1 = $dept_id;
    print views_embed_view('staff_rec',$display_id = 'default',$arg1 );
```

please advise,

thanks
billy

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're trying to do.. You need to use a view tpl for the entire view.

Click `Theme: Information` in your view. You'll need to get the tpl file for `Style output`.

You can find the tpl files in your `modules/views/theme` folder. Then you copy it into your theme folder and rename it to a file name in your Information pane like below.

[image]

Here is a basic example tpl I'm using for one of my views. It let's me loop each row and access each field and build the html from there. This will work with `views_embed_view()`.

```
views-view-unformatted--homework-pane.tpl.php

<?php 
    $arr_rows = $view->style_plugin->rendered_fields;
    foreach($arr_rows as $key=>$arr_row): 
        if (isset($arr_row['field_due_date'])) {
            $date_print = t('Due') . ": " .$arr_row['field_due_date'];
        } else {
            $date_print = t('Posted') . ": " .$arr_row['created'];
        } 
?>
<div class="todo-tasklist-item todo-tasklist-item-border-green">
    <div class="todo-tasklist-item-title"> <a class="use-ajax" href="/content-load/nojs/<?php print $arr_row['nid']; ?>"><?php print $arr_row['title']; ?></a> </div>
    <div class="todo-tasklist-controls pull-left">
        <span class="todo-tasklist-date"><?php print $date_print; ?> </span>
    </div>
</div>
<?php 
    endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: hello Niall,  THANK for your quick reply, will try and let you know. have a nice weekend..

Comment: Hello Nail, thanks for your help and sorry for late reply, for some reasons, i no longer request to use this function, but it's good to know how to do it.
thanks you.